# ReGex exclude character not giving correct result

Tags: java, regex, replace

In the following code, I am trying to add "@" to all occurrences of a name (but exclude the ones already with "@") with replaceAll.

```
name = "Bob"
message = "Hi Bob"
message = message.replaceAll("[^@]" + name, "@" + name);
```

I read online from *multiple* sources that to exclude a character, you would surround it with brackets, with a caret. After trying a few combinations, I found that if you have `message = "^Bob"`, it would somehow convert that into "@Bob".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<!\S)[A-Z]`  https://regex101.com/r/NqQaZt/1 And then replace with @ followed by the match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^@]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches and *consumes* any char other than `@`. Since you use `replaceAll`, the char matched with this pattern will get removed, and the `@` will get inserted together with the `name`.

You can use

```java
String name = "Bob";
String message = "Hi Bob";
message = message.replaceAll("\\b(?<!@)" + name + "\\b", "@$0");
System.out.println(message);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fiLq7T) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n3yIJ7/1).

*Details*:

- `\b(?<!@)` - a word boundary that is not preceded with a `@` char
- `Bob` - a word
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The `$0` in the replacement is the backreference to the whole match.

Comment: Hmm, it works, but I'd like to know why its much more complicated than I thought it would be. If you have some time, I'd appreciate if you could explain why my ReGex string didnt work. I am currently a bit confused why [^@] doesn't work.

Comment: @tenderporkk I added the explanation.

Comment: tyvm! I appreciate all the help :D Thanks for the explanation as well, it helped me understand a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Using `[^@]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) which  actually matches a single char other than `@` which can also match a `^` char.

You can use lookarounds assertions instead, which are non consuming and find the `name` surrounded by whitespace boundaries.

The pattern will be:

```
(?<!\S)Bob(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `Bob` Match literally
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

In the replacement, you can use the full match `$0` preceded by an `@`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahu3mh/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/AgZ3xl)

**Note** in Java to double escape the backslashes.

```
String name = "Bob";
String message = "Hi Bob";
message = message.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)" + name + "(?!\\S)", "@$0");
System.out.println(message);
```

Output

```
Hi @Bob
```

Comment: Ah ok, this makes a lot of sense. Tyvm for the regex, am still learning it :D

Comment: Well, I'm confused.  According to the OP this makes sense.  I get the same output and the OP says mine doesn't work.  And what is supposed to happen when you see `^Bob`?  My answer and the other one give `^@Bob`.  This one just gives `^Bob`.  Yet I still don't know where mine fails according to the OP.  That's all I want to know. I guess I'm not clear on the requirement.

Comment: @tenderporkk What should be the result of `^Bob` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

- `(?<!@)` + name says only if not preceded by an `@`

```
String test = "Bob @Bob @Bob Bob";
String name = "Bob";
String s = test.replaceAll("(?<!@)"+name, "@"+name);
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints

```
@Bob @Bob @Bob @Bob
```

Comment: I dont think this one works. I tested it out, and it doesn't add a @ before it

Comment: @tenderporkk would you please tell me how this failed?  For a string `String test = "Bob @Bob @Bob ^Bob"` it also returns `"Bob @Bob @Bob ^@Bob"`

Comment: My mistake, I tested the third line, and I didnt notice you used a new variable "s", so it appeared that it did nothing.